# In Jenkins how to use Docker image with cross compilation environment

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently trying to setup a Jenkins build Pipeline and I'm struggling including a docker container. My main problem is the way Jenkins sends build steps to the running container.

### Background

I'm building a cross compilation project. This happens in a linux, set up for cross compilation. All necessary stuff is provided by a SDK including the appropriate compilers, headers, libs, etc.

To setup everything, it also includes an environment file, which needs to be sourced by the current shell. This script adds necessary info, like adding environment variables (e.g. adjusting $PATH) or aliases.

For the Jenkins builds I'm creating a docker image containing the SDK. The image is working fine, and I'm able to build the project when I'm running the container. But it doesn't work on Jenkins. After some evaluation I found out that the problem lies in the way Jenkins uses the container.

### The problem

It seems Jenkins starts the container for a docker image in the background via `docker run -t -d imagename cat`. Then all subsequent build steps are sent using `docker exec`. This is usually fine. In my case I get errors, as all the executables (e.g. cmake) are not found. The executables are not installed in the regular system root but in the SDK folder.
I added a `source` command to the docker image's entrypoint script. The `source` command sources the SDK environment. As the entrypoint is only executed during `run` and not with `exec`, all build steps produce errors because the `$PATH` variable is not set properly.

This is a stripped down Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            label 'docker'
            image 'test:01'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                cmakeBuild  installation: "InSearchPath",
                            generator: "Unix Makefile",
                            buildDir: 'build',
                            sourceDir: 'source',
                            steps: [
                                [args: 'all install']
                            ]
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Which yields following log output:

```
...
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
$ docker run -t -d -u 1078:1001 -w /jenkins/workspace/project -v /jenkins/workspace/project:/jenkins/workspace/project:rw,z -v /jenkins/workspace/project@tmp:/jenkins/workspace/project@tmp:rw,z  test:01 cat
$ docker top ff1b4ee4e929b83e5741ef7db1e57688f7f996ca3a10a00ae4c5426cf108cb2a -eo pid,comm
...
...
...
[Pipeline] cmakeBuild
[build] $ docker exec --workdir /jenkins/workspace/project/build ff1b4ee4e929b83e5741ef7db1e57688f7f996ca3a10a00ae4c5426cf108cb2a cmake -G "Unix Makefile" /jenkins/workspace/project/source
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"cmake\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
...
```

### The reproduce image

To find out more about the behavior I created a small docker image which illustrates the problem.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie

# Add entrypoint script which sources envvars file
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash\n\n\
          . /envvars \n\n\
          exec \"\$@\"\
          " >/entrypoint.sh \
    && chmod ugo+rx /entrypoint.sh

# Add a script foo.sh which returns the content of $PATH
RUN mkdir -p /home/test/script \
    && echo "#!/bin/bash\n\
            echo \$PATH \n\
            " > /home/test/script/foo.sh \
    && chmod ugo+rx /home/test/script/foo.sh

# Add the directory containing the foo.sh script to $PATH
RUN echo "export PATH=/home/test/script:$PATH \n" > /envvars

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

You can build this image:

```
$> docker build -t "test" .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   55.3kB
Step 1/6 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> c9d6adb06e4d
Step 2/6 : RUN echo "#!/bin/bash\n\n          . /envvars \n\n          exec \"\$@\"          " >/entrypoint.sh     && chmod ugo+rx /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 648affce60a6
Step 3/6 : RUN mkdir -p /home/test/script     && echo "#!/bin/bash\n            echo \$PATH \n            " > /home/test/script/foo.sh     && chmod ugo+rx /home/test/script/foo.sh
 ---> Running in d13391c77668
Removing intermediate container d13391c77668
 ---> 7d88c20f8673
Step 4/6 : RUN echo "export PATH=/home/test/script:$PATH \n" > /envvars
 ---> Running in 55ac66323579
Removing intermediate container 55ac66323579
 ---> 35e081186bfa
Step 5/6 : ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
 ---> Running in 53154fed036f
Removing intermediate container 53154fed036f
 ---> 4ca347cbe757
Step 6/6 : CMD ["/bin/bash"]
 ---> Running in a598aefa837b
Removing intermediate container a598aefa837b
 ---> 78fc760bb9db
Successfully built 78fc760bb9db
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Once the image is built, you can run it interactively. So you are inside the container, in a bash shell, and can call `foo.sh` directly, because `/home/test/script` is part of `$PATH`:

```
$> docker run --rm -ti test
root@42529686fe22:/# foo.sh
/home/test/script:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
root@42529686fe22:/# exit
```

You can even override `CMD` setting from Dockerfile and call foo.sh from outside the container using `docker run`:

```
$> docker run --rm -t test foo.sh
/home/test/script:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

**But** when you start the container in the background (as it is done in Jenkins), you can't call `foo.sh` any more:

```
$> docker run --rm --name test -td test cat
0ecf3efecc54d33b73aaab6b4a1e191056c55597b3fe558ff7a7a6f93db2b695

$> docker exec test foo.sh
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"foo.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Though calling `foo.sh` using the absolute path works. The result shows that `$PATH` does not contain the script directory `/home/test/script`:

```
$> docker exec test /home/test/script/foo.sh
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

### The question

Do you know of any possibility I could configure either the docker image or the Jenkins pipeline to make my scenario work?

One possible solution I could think of, is wrapping all build steps in shell scripts, which itself source the environment file. But I would prefer to use the plugins provided by Jenkins and write a clean Jenkinsfile (i.e. not everything is hidden in shell scripts)

Another solution could be to install the SDK directly in the system root. But I'm not sure of side effects. Furthermore I still need specific environment variables set for the build step.

Comment: The error message implies that `cmake` is not installed your image.

Comment: It is installed, just not in the regular ˋ$PATHˋ. If I run the container and use an interactive bash cmake is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ENV in the Dockerfile to set the path:

```
ENV PATH="/home/test/script:${PATH}"
```

Then it should work with `docker run` or `docker exec`

```
$> docker exec test foo.sh
/home/test/script:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but I have many environment variables. So this solution could break in future with changing SDK revisions.

Comment: This would mainly solve the issue of not finding cmake in the $PATH; other environment variables could still be set in a script/environment file if you prefer. Is the file you mentioned included in the image or being mounted as a volume at run time?

Comment: The environment source file is included in the image

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure I see the difference of writing the variables in the Dockerfile versus a file baked into the image; you'd potentially have to update one or the other and rebuild the image for a new SDK anyway.